# Singly Linked List Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, google-colaboratory, singly-linked-list

This is the error which is the result of the code that I have run in my terminal

[image: Google Collab Output goes here]

I have some issue with my code, anyone can find the solution of this code?

```
class Node:
    # Node untuk singly Linkedlist
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = data
        
    class singly_linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        # Membuat list kosong
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0
        
    def print_all_item(self):
        # Iterate the list.
        current_item = self.head
        while current_item:
            val = current_item.data
            current_item = current_item.next
            print(val)
            
    def append_item(self, data):
        #menambahkan item pada list
        node = Node(data)
        if self.tail:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        self.count += 1
```

Test :

```
listPertama = singly_linked_list()
listPertama.append_item('PHP')
listPertama.append_item('Python')
listPertama.append_item('C#')
listPertama.append_item('C++')
listPertama.append_item('Java')
listPertama.print_all_item()
```

Expected Result :

```
PHP
Python
C#
C++
Java
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: (Note also that this code will generate an `IndentationError`. Please take care to always share accurate code. We shouldn't have to guess which errors are relevant and which aren't. Please see my earlier comment about how to do that easily.)

Comment: `self.next = data` This line in the `Node.__init__` method does not make sense. `next` is supposed to be another `Node`, not a string.

Comment: When you create a Node object, its next pointer should be None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the "data" in the fifth line to "None".

Like this class Node:

```py
# Node untuk singly Linkedlist
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```